# About solving for general solution of a planar system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: Solve for general solution $$y'=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 4 \\ -2 & -4 \end{bmatrix}y$$

Solving for eigenvalues, get $\lambda_1 =-2+2i$

$| A-\lambda_1 I|= \begin{bmatrix} 2-2i & 4 \\ -2 & -2-2i \end{bmatrix}$

$(2-2i)x+4y=0 \rightarrow v_1(eigenvector)=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ i-1 \end{pmatrix}$

> Question 1: for the matrix, why is not a must to row-reduce? Why is the second row redundant? Also does there exist other linearly-independent eigenvectors that also fit in here? Do initial conditions sort of limit the possibilities of different eigenvectors?

$\lambda_2=(2, -i-1)^T$

The fundamental solutions are $Z_1(t)=e^{(-2+2i)t}(2, i-1)^T$ and $Z_2(t)=e^{(-2-2i)t}(2,-i-1)^T$

Then the real-valued fundamental solutions are $y_1(t)=\frac{1}{2}(z_1+z_2)$ and $y_2(t)=\frac{1}{2i}(z_1-z_2)$

> Question 2: For the real-valued fundamental solutions, I don't understand why $y_1(t)=\frac{1}{2}(Z_1+Z_2)$ and $y_2(t)=\frac{1}{2i}(Z_1-Z_2)$? Where do those$\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2i}$ come from?

Comment: What does it mean to "solve derivative =matrix" ? Presumably there are two functions involved-y1 and y2, both being functions of some other variable, but what is meant on the other side of the equation? Did you leave out a column vector after the matrix?

Comment: @P.Lawrence Let me check... that was straight from my notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&4\\-2&-4\end{bmatrix}$$. The eigenvalues of A are $-2 \pm 2i$. For the eigenvalue -2+2i an eigenvector is
 $$\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}i$$.Let 
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$. Let $$\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $$\begin{bmatrix}u_1'\\u_2'\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}AP\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}$$ $$=\begin{bmatrix}-2&-2\\2&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}$$
whose general solution is $$u_1=e^{-2t}(C \cos(2t)+D\sin(2t)),$$
$$u_2=e^{-2t}(-D \cos(2t)+C\sin(2t)).$$. Now you can recover 
$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}$$